# have to click react button twice to get data from mutation

Tags: reactjs, apollo-client

I have a react component form. When I click the 'Submit" button it fires a mutation using the `useMutation` apollo hook. For some reason I have to click the button twice for the data to `console.log`.

Here is my code.

```
import React, { Fragment, useState, useEffect } from 'react';
import { useMutation, gql } from '@apollo/client';
import { useNavigate } from 'react-router-dom';
// import { saveTokens } from '../helpers/manageTokens';

const LOGIN_MUTATION = gql`
  mutation Mutation($email: String!, $password: String) {
    signIn(email: $email, password: $password) {
      accessToken
      refreshToken
    }
  }
`;

const Login = () => {
  const navigate = useNavigate();
  const [formState, setFormState] = useState({
    email: '',
    password: ''
  });

  const [login, { data, loading, error }] = useMutation(LOGIN_MUTATION);

  const emailChange = e => {
    setFormState({
      ...formState,
      email: e.target.value
    });
  };

  const passwordChange = e => {
    setFormState({
      ...formState,
      password: e.target.value
    });
  };

  const handleSubmit = e => {
    e.preventDefault();
    login({
      variables: {
        email: formState.email,
        password: formState.password
      }
    });
    console.log(data && data);
  };

  return (
    <Fragment>
      <div className='header-text'></div>
      <form action='' className='login-form' onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
        <div className='form-group'>
          <input
            type='email'
            value={formState.email || ''}
            onChange={emailChange}
            className='form-control'
            placeholder='Enter Email'
          />
        </div>
        <div className='form-group'>
          <input
            type='password'
            value={formState.password || ''}
            onChange={passwordChange}
            className='form-control'
            placeholder='Enter Password'
          />
        </div>
        <div className='form-group'>
          <div className='custom-control custom-checkbox'>
            <input
              type='checkbox'
              className='custom-control-input'
              id='customCheck1'
            />
            <label className='custom-control-label' htmlFor='customCheck1'>
              Remember me
            </label>
          </div>
        </div>
        <button type='submit' className='btn btn-submit btn-block submit'>
          Submit
        </button>
      </form>
    </Fragment>
  );
};

export default Login;
```

I am not sure why I have to click the button twice for the data to return from the api call. I have never had this happen before.